# Why can't I see Event Listener as an option under Choose Product part in Google Tag Manager

Tags: google-tag-manager

I'm trying to create an Auto Event Tracking tag in GTM. However, I can't find Event Listener option under product types. You can see the screenshots of two tags with and without Event Listener.
[image]
What am I missing?

Thanks for helping out.

Answer (score 2):

Are you wanting to fire a tag based on an event that occurs? From the looks of your tag name, Link Click Listener, you'll want to create a trigger that matches your criteria and then apply the trigger to the tag(s) you are creating. You needed to create event listeners in older versions of GTM, but the newer versions will automatically listen to link clicks. More info on auto-event triggers can be found [here](https://support.google.com/tagmanager/answer/6106716?hl=en).

[click listener trigger screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vad9w.png)